# Adding query results to enhanced list

Tags: apex, custom-view

Is there any possibilities of adding the query results to the `<apex:enhancedList>` in an VF page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just making an assumption regarding the meaning of *'the query results'* in your question. Are you saying you want to do your own query and display the results of it using the apex:enhancedList component? If so, the answer is no, this component does its own querying based on the users list view filters. However...

To display your own results consider either packaging your own list view which you can reference using this component or for more flexibility (queries can be dynamic) take a look at using the [apex:pageBlockTable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm) component. The Salesforce documentation has a good sample on it [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_iteration_components.htm). Also see other links below.

> A list of data displayed as a table within either an  or apex:pageBlockSection component, similar to a related list or list view in a standard Salesforce page

[image]

Here is a video I found demonstrating its use, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qL-fh-h1DU. Also a cool demo using it to display an [additional detail row](http://stachl.me/blog/2012/09/12/pageblocktable-detail-row.html) (i know not something you asked about, but ignore that this sitll gives you some keen further insight into the compoent).